# dist-update kernel failed?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, versions

I run:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

, and the linux kernel seemed to be updated to 3.2.0-31-generic successfully.

However, after I rebooted, I typed:

```
uname -a
```

, it showed :

```
Linux Albert-PC 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Does that means the kernel wasn't being updated? I didn't encounter any error or warning messages during the upgrade or dist-upgrade.

Thanks for any help

------------------------------------modified----------------------------------------

Dear January:

```
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic                      3.2.0-23.36                               Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic                      3.2.0-29.46                               Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-30-generic                      3.2.0-30.48                               Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-31-generic                      3.2.0-31.50                               Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                               3.2.0.31.34                               Generic Linux kernel imageou
```

Could you please explain what this command and the subsequent result means? Thank you~

Comment: Open a terminal, and type `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`. Post the results.

Comment: the latest kernel would be 3.2.0-31 . Give me the output of uname -r

Comment: I've commented the output under samrtboyhw's answer

Comment: Upon boot in your grub menu, what does it say? Ubuntu 3.XXX?

Comment: It's 3.2.0-29, not the latest 3.2.0-31

Answer (score 0):

The method is not the best. Please use `uname -r` to get the results. In my case I get

```
3.5.0-14-lowlatency
```

since I'm using Ubuntu Studio.

Comment: Dear smartboyhw : This is the result : "3.2.0-29-generic"